# Upload image into server using retrofit

Tags: android, request, retrofit2

I want to upload image/file to server using its uri using below code

```
try {

                    String descriptionString = "Sample description";
                    RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);

                    File file = new File(path);

                    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());

                    if (extension != null) {

                        String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(type), file);

                        MultipartBody.Part body2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("avatar", file.getName(), new FileRequestBody(file, extension));

                        Response<ResponseBody> response = ApiCaller.getProfileAPI().requestingUploadProfilePhoto("Bearer " + AuthenticationProvider.getInstance().token.token,
                                "form-data; name=avatar; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"",
                                ProfileProvider.getInstance().parsedProfile.profileId,
                                description,
                                body2).execute();
                        if (response.isSuccessful()){
                            Logger.msg("Photo", ": uploaded successfully " + uri);
                        }else{
                            Logger.msg("Photo", ": uploaded successfully none" + uri + response.errorBody().string());
                        }
                    }else{
                        Logger.msg("Photo", ":extension error");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

My API service for that request

```
 @Multipart
@POST("v1/avatar/profiles/{profileId}/upload")
Call<ResponseBody> requestingUploadProfilePhoto(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader,
                                                @Header("Content-Disposition") String content_type,
                                                @Path("profileId") String profileId,
                                                @Part("description") RequestBody description,
                                                @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

So, here my response is not successful. API returns me Internal Server error status 500, but I know that server works well(I tested it other application). Also, file uri is ok too. I am new here, so can someone find my mistake and explain in detail why it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if someone find it useful, mistake was in 1st parameter "name" here (in my case it should be "file" according to server, instead of "avatar")

```
MultipartBody.Part body2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("avatar", file.getName(), new FileRequestBody(file, extension));

Response<ResponseBody> response = ApiCaller.getProfileAPI().requestingUploadProfilePhoto("Bearer " + AuthenticationProvider.getInstance().token.token,
                            ProfileProvider.getInstance().parsedProfile.profileId,
                            body2).execute();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        Logger.msg("Photo", ": uploaded successfully " + uri);
                    }else{
                        Logger.msg("Photo", ": uploaded successfully none" + uri + response.errorBody().string());
                    }
```

So, it was enough to change it and remove all unnecessary stuff.
Also, of course, it is necessary to change service file, according to parameters. I did not pay attention to it enough, because in tutorials it was not mentioned as some important parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert your image to file and create a multipart request as below

```
    String fileName = "myFile";
    RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", fileName, reqFile);
```

To convert your image to file, use below function

```
    public static File convertBitmapToFile(Context mContext, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            File f = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "image");
            f.createNewFile();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
            byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();


            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            return compressImageFile(mContext, f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Retrofit Api Definition

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("/upload/image")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

For compressor function use below code

Add this in gradle

```
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'



public static File compressImageFile(Context mContext, File file) {
        try {
            return new Compressor(mContext).compressToFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return file;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why I should convert it to file? Moreover, when I check my image for type it is file.

Comment: If you convert it to file as above example it will upload to server and same can be accessed in android to show in a ImageView

Comment: Ok I will try, but can you give me where is method compressImageFile?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: what error are you getting? If its 500 internal server error. You might wanna check your server logs.

Comment: Yes it is Internal Server Error, but my server works fine. I read that such error can cause unacceptable format of file.

Comment: Server might be working. But still if you can check the logs you can find out the exact issue. I will suggest you to debug at server level logs first. What exactly is the error server shows

Comment: Ok, but problem is that server is not mine and I cannot get access to it. Thank you for trying, I will talk with my partner

Comment: Sure. Have a chat with the backend person. And Do let me know with any findings.

Comment: Thank you for dividing your time to my problem, I posted answer here

Comment: So, it was server related issue after all :P. No issues. Happy to help :)